# Codeigniter -> Edit Page

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am getting the following error when I try and access:

**domain.co.nz/admin/editpage/home/**

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCMSPage() on a non-object in controllers/home.php on line 22
```

The issue with this is that I cannot understand why it is being passed back into the main **“home” controller** - which is the main controller.

All of my models are loaded by default - http://cl.ly/2U1F3a2B0s2K0i3k3g13

**Ideal Situation**

What I am trying to do with this is load the content into a text area on for editing and when submit is clicked I would like it to go back to the same page with a message saying content updated.

**Admin Template**

```
<li><?php echo anchor('#','Edit Pages');?>
            <?php if(is_array($cms_pages)): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($cms_pages as $page): ?>
                        <li><a >permalink?>"><?=$page->name?></a></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
```

**Page Model**

```
function updatePage($data){
        $data = array('content' => $content);
        $this ->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('pages',$data);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<?php
//Setting form attributes
$formpageEdit = array('id' => 'pageEdit', 'name' => 'pageEdit');
$formInputTitle = array('id' => 'title', 'name' => 'title');
$formTextareaContent = array('id' => 'content', 'name' => 'content');
?>

<section id = "validation"><?php echo validation_errors();?></section>

<h4><?= $title ?> </h4>
<?php
echo form_open('admin/editpage/'.$page->permalink, $formpageEdit);
echo form_fieldset();
echo form_label ('Content', 'content');
echo form_textarea("content", $page['content']);
echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
echo form_fieldset_close();
echo form_close();
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
function index(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

        }else{
            redirect('admin/home');
        }
       $page = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPage($this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
        $data['title'] = $page->name;
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/editpage', array('page' => $page, TRUE));

        $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data);

    }
```

Comment: need the whole controller function

Comment: Please post the getCMSPage() methods from your navigation_model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this line
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/editpage', $data);
// needs to be
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/editpage', array('page' => $page, TRUE);
```

Comment: When I access:  http://domain.co.nz/admin/editpage/uriseg I get Call to a member function getCMSPage() on a non-object in /House/application/controllers/home.php on line 22

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really tested this yet but it should give you a good start. What you're asking is quite a bit of work to fully code out quickly.

This is the page_model model it's essentially what you posted with a few minor tweaks. Its best to use id's rather than strings. You may also want to do some htmlspecialchars or mysql hijack validation prior to passing these to your DB.

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the Page_model model, this model handles the retrieval and modification of all pages.
 *
 **/
class Page_model extends CI_Model {
/**
 * the getCMSPage function retrieves the data from the db given the ID that was passed via $id.
 **/
    function getCMSPage($id = NULL) {
        $this->db->where('permalink', $permalink);
        $query = $this->db->get('pages', 1);

        #check to make sure row's were returned, if so continue, otherwise return false.
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            #set the results into an array and return $row, should return $row['content'], and $row['id'];
            #if you were editing more than one page this is where you would use a foreach($query)
            $row = $query->result_array();
            return $row;
        }else{
            return false;
        }// END if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    }// END function getCMSPage()
}// END Page_model class
?>
```

This is the site controller and for sake of time i just echo'd your form_textarea straight from the edit function.. you shouldn't do this as it goes against MVC standards. You should create a view for that portion of the section.

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the Site controller, primary controller for your site.
 *
 **/
class Site extends CI_Controller {
/**
 * construct function, in our case we are going to load the Posts_model , you may not want to do this.
 * 
 **/
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        #load Page_model, should be located in app/models/page_model.php
        $this->load->model('Page_model');
    }//END function __construct();

/**
 * edit function, this function handles retrieval of the page from the URI, and the page's content for editing.
 *
 * This function uses $id which auto retrieves the page's ID from the uri. Your URL should look similiar to:
 * http://yourdomain.com/site/edit/3/yourunecessaryinformationhere
 * everything after the id is not really required but could help with SEO.
 * 
 **/
    function edit($id){
        #retrieve the page's content in array form.
        $page = $this->Page_model->getCMSPage($id);
        echo form_textarea("content", $page['content']);
    }
}//END Site Class
```

Keep in mind i wrote this up in 5-10 minutes so its rushed and not very well commented or even tested but itll give you a great head start. This only gives you an example of how to retrieve information from the DB and echo it into a textarea. You would still need to create another function within your page_model to insert/update the information and another snippet of code in your controller to pass the edited content to the model.

You can hit me up on AIM or twitter if you have more questions ThirdGenSup, twitter is @gorelative

Comment: Mike,I have done what you have said above,  But every time I access the "permalink" page it seems to think that it is my main "home controller"